# mv command - parametric source and target

Tags: unix, find, mv

I have folder "F A" containing some subfolders and files and another folder "F B" containing the same folder structure but no file:

```
find . -type d
.
./F A
./F A/SF A
./F A/SF B
./F A/SF C
./F B
./F B/SF A
./F B/SF B
./F B/SF C
```

**How can I write a `mv` command to move any file under "F A" to its equivalent folder in "F B"?**

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} "./F B" \;
```

will just `mv` any file under "F A" to "F B", but not in its correct subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the relative path twice:

```
find ./FolderA -type f -exec mv "{}" "./FolderB/{}" \;
```